# install_name_tool error for Android/sdk

Tags: android, scala, sbt, homebrew

I am getting the following error:

```
$ brew install  sbt 
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool
$
```

when I run the install_name_tool I get the following error:

```
$ install_name_tool
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Users/<myhome>/Library/Android/sdk" cannot be located.
install_name_tool: error: unable to find utility "install_name_tool", not a developer tool or in PATH
$
```

Actually the Android SDK is installed in the path which was installed using Android Studio.

```
/Users/<myhome>/Library/Android/sdk
```

I am trying to install brew for installing scala & sbt. I have xocde editor already installed

```
$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
$
```

Comment: What? Installing brew is like a 1 line curl command iirc

Comment: Yes, I have un-installed and reinstalled brew but that did not help either!

Comment: You're running `install_name_tool`, what is it, it's completely unrelated to android and sbt

Comment: Adding the steps I came to `install_name_tool`

Comment: You need to install xcode

Comment: I have xocde editor already installed. But if I hit `xcode` on the command prompt nothing happens is there anything else that you are talking about? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I don't know, something about your setup is screwed up. This is a problem with brew and/or your environment.